# Difference between Pandas' apply() and Python's map() when creating new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I have a `df` containing some references for my projects, such like this:

```
           root_path   Credentials
Project1   path/to/    cred1.json
Project2   path/to/    cred2.json
Project3   path/to/    cred3.json
```

I need a third column `Client` to save the response of the connection to BigQuery API, which is an object. The argument to pass to the function is the string formed by `df['root_path'] + df['Credentials']`. For this, I tried with this two queries:

1. Using `apply()`

   `df['Client'] = df.apply(lambda x : bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json((df['root_path'] + df['Credentials']).values), axis = 1)`
2. Using `map()`

   `df['Client'] = map(lambda root,bq : bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(root + bq), df['root_path'], df['Credentials'])`

Finally, the second query gave me the result I wanted. Could someone explain me why the second works and the first not? As far as I understand, it's because the first query returns everytime the whole series of objects, and the second calls the function row by row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #1 looks kind of suspicious to me since you aren't using the lambda variable `x`.

Comment: Change `df` inside the `lambda` function to `x` and do not call [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) (deprecated btw for newer [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)).